# Remove lines without n number of a specific character?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a file with many lines delimited by either `#` or `:` and I want to remove all of the lines that do not have 3 pounds of 4 colons. This is what I tried:

```
awk '! /^\#{3}\:{4}+$/' "$file"
```

Edit to provide sample lines:

```
958#40#6#020104
Thanhachammet,Chendrit:D500:5833:8.40:12.10
This is # bad : line
```

I wan't to take all lines like 1 and 2 and send them to a file excluding all lines like #3. Some of

Comment: Your regex is looking for lines which are only ### followed by 4 or more colons (i.e. no other characters whatsoever). Is that maybe part of the issue?

Comment: do you mean **continuous** 3 # **or** 4 `:` ? better show some examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extended regexp passed to grep should do it:

```
grep -E '(#.*#.*#|:.*:.*:.*:)' file.txt
```

On Ubuntu 12.04:

```
$ cat file.txt 
958#40#6#020104
Thanhachammet,Chendrit:D500:5833:8.40:12.10
This is # bad : line
$ grep -E '(#.*#.*#|:.*:.*:.*:)' file.txt 
958#40#6#020104
Thanhachammet,Chendrit:D500:5833:8.40:12.10
$
```

If you need to match much more than 3 or 4 `#` or `:`, then you could do this:

```
grep -E '((#.*){2}#|(:.*){3}:)' file.txt
```

If you prefer [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), you could do this:

```
awk '/(#.*#.*#|:.*:.*:.*:)/' file.txt
```

[This debugging tool is really handy when debugging regular expressions.](https://www.debuggex.com/)

[Debuggex Demo of this regular expression](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VbpV3WY9ODaEzhlj)

Comment: Better yet use: `$ grep -E '(#[^#]*#[^#]*#|:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:)' file.txt` which is a bit more efficient as it cuts out a lot of backtracking.

Comment: This will allow more than the specified number of occurrences, though.

Comment: You still need anchors, and a trailing repeat star for the last negated expression in each group.

Comment: @tripleee - Oops - Yes, you're right - I copied the wrong command. If you need exactly 3 `#` or 4 `:`, then this should suffice:  `grep -E '^(([^#]*#){3}[^#]*|([^:]*:){4}[^:]*)$' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk 'split($0, a, "#") == 4 || split($0, a, ":") == 5' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`'s `--invert-match` (`-v` for short):

```
grep -v '#{3}|:{4}' "$file"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It assumes the 3 `#` or 4 `:` are contiguous, which is not true in the OP's input data.